# Hiding some part of code base using Git

Tags: git, github

We are using Github for our project, and thinking about hiring a contractor for some part of a project. Is it possible to expose only some part of the code base to the contractor using Github? If not, what tool should we use?

Thank you.

Comment: You may also find this recently asked question helpful: [Git: Ignore files for public repository, but not for private](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721984/git-ignore-files-for-public-repository-but-not-for-private)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently came across [git subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree), which could be used to assist with splitting and merging a subdirectory of changes to a contractor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use submodules (there is also [GitHub help on submodules](http://help.github.com/submodules/)), if the code you can reveal is in separate directory.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is used a private repo host for non-public work (unfuddle.com and now bitbucket offers this). Depending on the nature of the work, you can link with submodules. If the work is on the same repo you can just have another remote and be mindful of what branches you are pulling and pushing.