# Git workflow for private files in open source repository

Tags: git

I'm open sourcing a website I'm working on, and need to exclude some files (tos, privacy policy, etc) from the public repository that I'll be publishing at GitHub.

What workflow would you suggest that allows to keep those files tracked in Git, preferably in the same repository (I'm working with heroku, and its not very convenient to deploy applications with multiple repos), but exclude them from the public repository?

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide#316062

Comment: If you want to track files locally but **not** push them to GitHub, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556807/track-files-locally-but-never-allow-them-to-be-pushed-to-the-remote-repository

Comment: @Lucio I know how to ignore files, but I don't want to ignore those files. I want to track their modifications with Git, and I also need to be able to push it to production on Heroku

Comment: @tehsockz multiple repos and symlinks/submodules isn't very convenient with PaaS providers like Heroku. They expect the app to come as a single repository with all the relevant data. I could use submodules and have Heroku fetch it from another server, but then I would have to authenticate Heroku somehow, and I'm not quite sure how that can be done.

Comment: @shesek then you're really out of luck with git, afaik. Why do you need to exclude the TOS and privacy policy, anyways?

Comment: @tehsockz my lawyer insists on that.