# Publishing an app, which sensitive data should I delete?

Tags: android

I created Android app using Android Studio for my bachelor´s thesis. I have to submit my Android Studio project, which will be on schools website and anyone could downloaded.

Are there any sensitive data, which I should delete before publishing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any API keys for any external API  you are using.

MD5 hashes or Google play store strings.

Keystore files.

.idea files which might have your name or computer name.

Can't really think of anything else.

Answer (score 1):

You public repo should not have secret keys.

Some useful links for hiding secret keys

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34021467/6891563

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46962852/6891563